# Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'builder') .net core 6

Tags: c#, dotnet-cli

Olá, estou tentando utilizar o EF no .NET CORE 6.0, porém está a apresentar um erro de "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'builder')" ao tentar adicionar uma nova migration "Add-Migration", o código funciona em .net core 5.0, houve mudanças para o 6.0?

Como podemos ajustar para que isso funcione?

Essa é minha DB Context

```
public IDbConnection Connection => Database.GetDbConnection();
    public ApplicationDbContext (DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<LoginModel> Logins { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Carro> Carros { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CarteiraVirtual> CarteirasVirtuais { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Estacionamento> Estacionamentos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Reserva> Reservas { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new CarroMap());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new CarteiraMap());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new EstacionamentoMap());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new ReservaMap());

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
```

Meu Program.cs:

```
    var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Estacionamento");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(x => 
    x.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
var app = builder.Build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blz?

Eu passei pelo mesmo problema que você e passei horas para encontrar o erro e a solução.

Um dos motivos pelo qual esse erro está ocorrendo é nos relacionamentos entre os objetos.

Por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso aconteceu comigo e as pessoas podem pensar "Como não viu esse erro?!!!"
Ocorre que esse é apenas um exemplo simples. Quando a aplicação está com diversas classes, a coisa complica um pouco.

Dica:
Quando você tenta adicionar um novo migration e ocorre esse erro, o Package Manager Console informa quais objetos estão com problema e precisam ser revistos.

Adaptei um dos meus erros abaixo para você entender que há dicas na saída dos erros.

```
There are multiple relationships between 'Carro' and 'Reserva' without configured foreign key properties. This will cause Entity Framework to create shadow properties on 'Carro' with names dependent on the discovery order. Consider configuring the foreign key properties using the [ForeignKey] attribute or in 'OnModelCreating'.
```